# Xampp and MySQL not started

Tags: mysql, xampp

This problem came from nowhere.

My xampp mysql service is not started. This is what it shows in Xampp log.

```
8:20:27 AM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
8:20:27 AM  [mysql]     Executing ""c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini" --standalone"
8:20:28 AM  [mysql]     Return code: 0
8:20:28 AM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
8:20:29 AM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
8:20:29 AM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
8:20:29 AM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing  dependencies, 
8:20:29 AM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
8:20:29 AM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and    check
8:20:29 AM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
8:20:29 AM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
8:20:29 AM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

and there is the log file

```
151206  8:24:31 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
151206  8:24:31 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151206  8:24:31 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
151206  8:24:31 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
151206  8:24:31 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
151206  8:24:31 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
151206  8:24:31 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
151206  8:24:31 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
151206  8:24:31 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
151206  8:24:31 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
151206  8:24:31 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
151206  8:24:31 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com)  5.6.22-72.0 started; log sequence number 1602572
151206  8:24:31 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly its due to blocked `ports`. By Default `MySql` run on port `3306`.

> Check which application is using port `3306`

In `Xampp > Click NetStat` it will show you all application with there running ports.

Once you find which application is running on port `3306`. Kill(close) that application and try starting `MySql` now it should now work fine.

If you need the other application(who was using port `3306`) make sure `Mysql` start first so the other application find some other port to start.

If this method doesn't work simply change the `port` for `MySql`

To change `MySql port` edit `php.ini` on `line 1262`(yours might be different) and change `MySql port` from `3306` to any number between `0 to 65536` and make sure these ports are not used by any other application

If still not working re installation of `xampp` might help fix the problem

Comment: there is nothing using port 3306 and i tried to change the port give the same result my friend.

Comment: did the eseat smart security cause any problem with ports,

Comment: also i open the port and allow all type of connection in firewall, and allow all allowed port in eset antivirus.

Comment: Then blocked ports is not causing issue.. Try Xampp reinstallation was it working before? What you did that caused this problem . Review your recent activity on computer that can possible cause this problem like recently installed new programs change settings or something else

Comment: it was working before and i tried to figure what happen nothing abnormal.