# MySql stops automatically

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

**I Get This Error Message**
    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
    If you need more help, copy and post this
    entire log window on the forums

[image]

Comment: Have you *checked the Windows Event Viewer for more clues*? Have you *posted the log text to the XAMPP forum*?

Comment: plx if you accepted my answer, upvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already have mysql running from different distribution ([appserv](https://www.appserv.org/en/%20*appserv*)) on the same port (3306).

You are inside a XAMPP control panel. which is different Windows LAMP distribution  ([xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html%20*xampp*))  which cannot start/stop appserv's mysql server instance.

IMHO you should pick one and uninstall other.

Answer (score 0):

You should try have a look on this post, the MySQL port (3306) is in use or blocked:

[Xampp and MySQL not started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114734/xampp-mysql-not-started)

Comment: Thank you. I solved it. 
I had appserv aldo installed in my pc.
I uninstalled it, MySql Started.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running this in command shell:

```
netstat -b -p TCP
```

Look for the results under local address. It will be something like 'localhost:3306'. It will list the port and the applications using it. Check the application that is listed for 3306

Comment: Thank you. I solved it. 
I had appserv aldo installed in my pc.
I uninstalled it, MySql Started.