# My XAMPP server has stopped working in the middle of my project

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

My xampp server has stopped working in the middle of my project, I have no clue what has caused this or how to fix it. All help would be very appreciated im just a starter in the IT-world. Thank you!

```
enter code here
10:17:32  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
10:17:32  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:17:32  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:17:32  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another 
method.
10:17:32  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:17:32  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:17:32  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:17:32  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

This is the event viewer.

```
2020-04-27 11:32:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows 
interlocked functions
2020-04-27 11:32:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-04-27 11:32:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-04-27 11:32:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-04-27 11:32:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-04-27 11:32:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 
16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-04-27 11:32:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-04-27 11:32:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are 
active.
2020-04-27 11:32:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary 
tables
2020-04-27 11:32:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 
'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; 
Please wait ...
2020-04-27 11:32:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size 
is now 12 MB.
2020-04-27 11:32:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-04-27 11:32:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 
47082; transaction id 9
2020-04-27 11:32:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from 
C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-04-27 11:32:21 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-04-27 11:32:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200427 
11:32:21
2020-04-27 11:32:21 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Hi, seems that could be an duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41554429/mysql-stops-automatically , see if that helps you

Comment: This question is very broad, as error says this can be due too many reason, you beter backup your files and reinstall xamp

Comment: Did you check with event viewer. the mysql log is a  bit short on details

Comment: this is the event viewer.